how to recall values from a column with a measure or calculated column
I want to create a measure or calculated column (I don't know what is needed between these two) that displays me all the values of a given column in a table or other chart. How can I write this function?
I have created this measure
sales = selectcolumns(ART, ART[vend]) but if I try to put this measure in the table, no value is displayed.
How can I fix this?
thanks!
This is because I imported the tables with direct query, but I want to divide certain columns and measures into categories. And the 'only way to do that, is to create calculated measures or columns and put them in folders/categories.

Please provide sample data and your expected ouptput.

maybe try this:
measureSales = CONCATENATEX
                       (DISTINCT(YourTable[ColumnName]), 
                        YourTable[ColumnName], 
                        ", ")

